# Would it possible by using GCM?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-actionbar, google-api

I am trying to develop an android app which will set reminder on other's phone.

Setting reminder is easy on phone in which application is currently running but how to set reminder on others phone via internet?

Let me be more specific , is it possible by GCM (Google cloud messaging)?

Any comments will be appreciated

Comment: I think It should be possible with `XMPP` connection server since the connection need to bidirectional - `C2D` and `D2C`. Please try your hands. Once the Notification is received, you need to make it to set the alarm on the client application

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible . Here's how using GCM:

1. From your app , register the device for gcm, a unique key will be generated ,send that unique key to your server and store that key at backend(database). Remember that each android phone on which you have installed your app will have a unique key.
2. Now to set reminder on other phone on which your application is installed , consider this scenario :
   I have installed your app on my phone and you have done the same on yours. Now i want to set reminder on your phone , I will make a post request which will contain the reminder data and and the freind name ,to the server. Server will verify that friend name on its database and will look for its unique GCM key. Once the GCM key is found and the freind is verified on your server , a request will be made by your server to the GOOGLE CLOUD MESSAGING server which will recongnize the GCM KEY from the request , now GCM SERVER will forward the message to you and you can extract the required message from that message.
3. Conclusion : GCM Message will be sent to that device only whose unique GCM key is targeted or registered on your server.

Comment: Oh ! Thank you very much for giving response. Would GCM be able to forward messages automatically ?

Comment: yes GCM will automatically forward your message to the receiver(Android Phone) , but its your server's duty to forward the message to the GCM server . :) .... cheers